# Добавить задачу в проект и сделать ее первой

Tags: c#, task, sharepoint, project

Как добавить задачу в проект в `SharePoint` через класс `TaskCreationInformation`, чтобы она стала первой в списке задач?
Там есть только свойства `AddAfterId` и `Parent` - и то и то подразумевает, что новая задача будет идти после какой-либо.

Дополнение для комментария ниже: Год 2013.
Код (вернее его попытка т.к. решение не работает - задача добавляется в конец списка):

```
TaskCreationInformation nt = new TaskCreationInformation();
nt.Name = "Task name5";
nt.Start = DateTime.Today;
nt.Duration = "20д";
nt.Id = Guid.NewGuid();
nt.ParentId = Guid.Empty; //Или nt.AddAfterId = Guid.Empty; 

draftProj.Tasks.Add(nt);
projContext.Load(draftProj.Tasks);
```

Comment: вы хотя бы код покажите и версию SharePoint/Project укажите?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил таким способом - через базу данных найти ID корневой задачи по ID проекта и ставить ее ID в AddAfterID